# Get src of image in button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button with an image on it. How can I get the `src` of that image on the button in JavaScript?

This is the HTML:

```
<button id="A8" name="B_Rook" type="button" style="background-color:#FFE4C4" onClick="check(this.id)">
    <a href="" onclick="getImgId(this.id)"><img id="B_Rook" src="B_Rook.jpg" HEIGHT=80 width=80/></a>
</button>
```

Comment: An `<a>` should not be nested in a `<button>`.

Comment: i have removed it,but its not working. i have sent u a mail regarding this,please check and reply me

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure what you are trying to do but...

To get the src of the image in the button tag do this

```
<button id="A8" name="B_Rook" type="button" style="background-color:#FFE4C4">
    <img id="B_Rook" src="B_Rook.jpg" HEIGHT=80 width=80 onclick="getImgId(this.src)">
</button>
```

to get an id of that img element do this

```
<button id="A8" name="B_Rook" type="button" style="background-color:#FFE4C4">
    <img id="B_Rook" src="B_Rook.jpg" HEIGHT=80 width=80 onclick="getImgId(this.id)">
</button>
```

and a basic click handler will look like this for both

```
<script>
    function getImgId(id){
        alert(id)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really close, just move the `onclick` from the `a` element to the `img` element.

You probably want to remove the `a` element entirely, as it's invalid HTML (`button` elements can't contain any [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) elements).

Also, unless you're writing XHTML (and you almost certanly aren't), there shouldn't be a `/` before the `>` at the end of your `img` tag. (It's harmless and allowed, it's just pointless.)

Comment: Thanks for your response,but im not getting the if for it,please help me